# How to get only the latest row from a window

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am working with Kinesis Analytics and I am trying to understand how to write my application to give me a sliding window over 24 hours. What I have generates the right data, but it looks like it regenerates it every time, which might be what it's supposed to do and my own ignorance prevents me from looking at the problem right?

What I want to do:

I have a few devices that feed a Kinesis Stream, which this Kinesis analytics application is hooked up to.

Now, when a record comes in, what I want to do is `SUM` a value over the last 24 hours and store that. So after Kinesis Analytics does it's job I'm connecting it to a Lambda to finalize some things.

My issue is, when I simulate sending in some data, 5 records in this case, everything runs, it runs multiple times, not 5. It LOOKS like each time a record comes in it redoes everything in the window (expected) which triggers the lambda for each row that's emitted. As the table grows, it's bad news. What I really want is just the latest value from the window from `NOW - 24 HOUR`, with the `"id"` field so I can join that "id" back to a record stored elsewhere.

My Application looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DEVICE_STREAM" (
    "id" VARCHAR(64),
    "timestamp_mark" TIMESTAMP,
    "device_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "property_a_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "property_b_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "value" DECIMAL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "DEVICE_PUMP" AS
    INSERT INTO "DEVICE_STREAM"
    SELECT STREAM "id",
        "timestamp_mark",
        "device_id",
        "x_id",
        "y_id",
        SUM("value") OVER W1 AS "value",
    FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
    WINDOW W1 AS (
        PARTITION BY "device_id", "property_a_id", "property_b_id" ORDER BY "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME
        RANGE INTERVAL '24' HOUR PRECEDING
    );
```

Hmmm.. this might be a better idea, Do the aggregation in a sub-select and select from that. It looks like I need that second window (`W2` below) to ensure I get each record that was given back out.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DEVICE_STREAM" (
    "id" VARCHAR(64),
    "timestamp_mark" TIMESTAMP,
    "device_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "property_a_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "property_b_id" VARCHAR(64),
    "value" DECIMAL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "DEVICE_PUMP" AS
    INSERT INTO "DEVICE_STREAM"
    SELECT STREAM s."id",
        s."timestamp_mark",
        s."device_id",
        s."property_a_id",
        s."property_b_id",
        v."value"
    FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" OVER W2 AS s, (
        SELECT STREAM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"."ROWTIME", "id",
            "timestamp_mark",
            "device_id",
            "property_a_id",
            "property_b_id",
            SUM("value") OVER W1 AS "value",
            FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
            WINDOW W1 AS (
                PARTITION BY "device_id", "property_a_id", "property_b_id" ORDER BY "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME
                RANGE INTERVAL '24' HOUR PRECEDING
            )
        ) AS v
    WHERE s."id" = v."id"
    WINDOW W2 AS (
        RANGE INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
    );
```

Also I notice that if I restart the Kinesis Analytics application, the `SUM` values reset, so clearly it doesn't persist across restarts, which might make it unsuitable for this solution. I might have to just setup a SQL server and periodically delete old records.

Answer (score 0):

In general using Streaming Analytics solutions (and Kinesis Analytics in particular) is recommended when you need to do something based on the data in the events and not something external like wall clock time.

The reason is simple: if you need to do something once every 24h, you create a job bringing the data from storage (DB) once, performing your task and then "going to sleep" for another 24h - no complexities, manageable overhead. Now if you need to do something based on the data (e.g. when SUM of some field across multiple events exceeds X) you are in trouble with conventional solution since there is no simple criteria for when it should run. If you run it periodically, it might be invoked many times until the data driven criteria is met, creating a clear overhead.

In the latest case Streaming Analytics solution will be used as designed and trigger your logic just when needed, minimizing the overhead.

If you prefer using Streaming Analytics (which I personally don't recommend based on description of your problem), but struggling with Kinesis Analytics syntax, you might consider using [Drools Kinesis Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B075MDR5DC). Among its features are [crons](http://support.streamx.co/samples-and-walkthroughs/timer-cron-and-calculation) and [collectors](http://support.streamx.co/language-reference/collect-from), which provide you with very simple way to trigger jobs on time basis.

- Note, that my answer is biased since I'm a CTO at Streamx.